# Showing relation for $n\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{n-1}$

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, induction

I'd like to show: $$n\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n-1}f(x) = \left(\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n}\,x-x\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n}\right)f(x)$$

I have no idea where this theorem comes from but I just have to show it is true.

I tried induction but didn't succeed

$\textsf{step 1: for $n = 1$ the equation is right}$

$\textsf{step 2: setting $n \to n+1:$}$
$$\begin{align}(n+1)\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n}f(x) &= \left(\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n+1}\,x-x\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n+1}\right)f(x)\\[12pt] &= \left(\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n}\,1\,f(x)+x\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n+1}\,f(x)-x\,\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\right)^{\textstyle n+1}f(x)\right)\end{align}$$

but somehow the sides are not equal. Any derivation?

Comment: Double-check your inductive step  calculations with identity $1$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Additional_identities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful not to commute the differentiation operator with $x$. Here is one way to prove the statement. Abbreviate $f'(x) \triangleq \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) $. Then,
\begin{align*}
\left( \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n+1} x - x \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n+1}  \right) f(x) &=  \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^n (f(x)+xf'(x)) - x\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n+1}f(x) \\
&= \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n-1}f'(x) + \left( \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^nxf'(x) -x\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^n f'(x) \right) \\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n-1}f'(x) + n \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n-1}f'(x) \\
&= (n+1) \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^{n}f(x),
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ is by induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for the hint and even writing it out! Just briefly, do you know where the theorem comes from?

Comment: @Leon You're welcome! To be honest, no. Your post was the first time I have seen it.